# SubString in excel using formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2016

Here are few example strings i have :

```
Md. Suman Kabir, Manager
Patrick J Trump, President
John Kennedy
```

Expected Output:

```
Suman Kabir
J Trump
Kennedy
```

For this i tried this formula:

```
=MID(A1, FIND(" ", A1) + 1, FIND(",", A1)- FIND(" ", A1) -1)
```

And i am getting correct output for the first two strings, but getting `ERROR` for the third one. Can anybody please point me the wrong in the formula or any other formula to have the expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just fixed by adding `&","` in this part `FIND(",", A1)` and become `FIND(",", A1&",")`

Then, the formula in `B1`  copy down :

```
=MID(A1,FIND(" ",A1)+1,FIND(",",A1&",")-FIND(" ",A1)-1)
```

[image]

Comment: Good idea! I am going to using this.

Answer (score 1):

Hi this seems to work: -

```
=IFERROR(MID(A3, FIND(" ", A3) + 1, FIND(",", A3)- FIND(" ", A3) -1),MID(A3, FIND(" ", A3) + 1, LEN(A3)- FIND(" ", A3) ))
```

So this does your part and if it errors due to the comma not being present it does a similar formula without the comma.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This part `FIND(",", A1)` gives an error because of no comma. You can put a condition at the beginning of the formula.

```
=IF(COUNTIF(A1,"*,*")>0,MID(A1, FIND(" ", A1) + 1, FIND(",", A1)- FIND(" ", A1) -1),RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND(" ",A1)))
```